# Online credit card payment processing on behalf of others

Tags: c#, paypal, payment-gateway

Does anyone know a way to facilitate payment between two parties via our website similar to how eBay facilitates payments between sellers and buyers, with buyers using their credit cards to make the purchases?  We built a solution around PayPal, but now PayPal is telling us that we cannot use it because that is against the credit card association rules.

Here's what they wrote:

Per our Acceptable Use Policy, under credit card association rules, PayPal
cannot permit the use of the PayPal service as a funding method for payment
processors to collect payments on behalf of merchants.

I would be greatful for any leads.  As a start-up, third-party payment aggregation services are very cost-prohibitive.

Comment: Consider e-gold.  I don't know much about it, but I think they cater to a 'broader market.'

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: My apologies if it doesn't seem to be programming-related--I know there are many knowledgeable folks on this site eager to help, that's why I posted it here.  

I also hope that a software developer similar to myself trying to launch an e-buiness might benefit from the answer to my question.  Again, my apologies if this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set yourself up as an escrow service between the buyers and sellers.  Rentacoder.com does something like this: http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/SoftwareBuyers/SoftwareBuyerFAQ.aspx#SafeProjectEscrow

If you are looking to move away from paypal and not be an escrow service yourself, look at escrow.com and its competitors to just use an escrow service.